# CSS Not Found Codeigniter 4

Tags: jquery, css, codeigniter, codeigniter-4

I have a problem with css include in Codeiginiter 4.

When I access this routes *localhost/my_project/user_role* all of the css included successfully.
But, when I access this routes *localhost/my_project/user_role/add* there is 2 error that css net::ERR_ABORTED 404(Not Found)

[image]

I take a look at network tab in my web inspector, bootstrap.min.css and app.min.css is included and the status code is 200 but it still showing not found error
[image]

This is how i load the css file
[image]

And this is my htaccess file

```
# Disable directory browsing
Options All -Indexes
 
# ----------------------------------------------------------------------
# Rewrite engine
# ----------------------------------------------------------------------
 
# Turning on the rewrite engine is necessary for the following rules and features.
# FollowSymLinks must be enabled for this to work.
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    Options +FollowSymlinks
    RewriteEngine On
 
    # If you installed CodeIgniter in a subfolder, you will need to
    # change the following line to match the subfolder you need.
    # http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritebase
    # RewriteBase /
 
    # Redirect Trailing Slashes...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
      RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]
 
    # Rewrite "www.example.com -> example.com"
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$ [NC]
    RewriteRule ^ http://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
 
    # Checks to see if the user is attempting to access a valid file,
    # such as an image or css document, if this isn't true it sends the
    # request to the front controller, index.php
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^([\s\S]*)$ index.php/$1 [L,NC,QSA]
 
    # Ensure Authorization header is passed along
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
</IfModule>
 
<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
    # If we don't have mod_rewrite installed, all 404's
    # can be sent to index.php, and everything works as normal.
    ErrorDocument 404 index.php
</IfModule>
 
# Disable server signature start
    ServerSignature Off
# Disable server signature end
```

How could i solve this problem ? Please help

Comment: Add the .htaccess to your question and the code where you're loading the css in your views so we can see how you're loading it.

Comment: @marcogmonteiro Please re read my question. I have included it

Comment: Try changing the way you are loading the css to something like base_url('path/to/your/file.css'). If that does not work, in your network tab, the 404 you're getting does it come from codeigniter or from apache/nginx?

Comment: what is your `base_url()` ? check  in config, I think you are including extra slash after base url to load css. just cross check it

Answer (score 1):

The new CI4 has a different structure than the previous versions.
Now there is a public folder. I would suggest you put frontend assets into the public folder so your loading is much simpler and you do not have to include `base_url` i.e.:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/style.css">
```

Comment: This is helpful. Moving frontend assets to public folder is important. But in this case URL will be change to : <link rel="stylesheet" href="public/assets/css/style.css">